# how to setup cors for get requests in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, methods, cors

I have been reading and trying these two configurations for `npm cors`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var whitelist = ['http://example1.com', 'http://example2.com']
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    }
}
```

this at first, this seem to work well but then I just figured...
this only works with `post` methods not `get` methods..

`get` will return the error....

What I want to do is...I have a different backend apis which have `get` and `post` method.

I use another another to call the `get` and `post` method from this api.

for example, frontend uses `example.this-one.com` and try to send `get` / `post request` to `example.that-two.com` as mentioned `post` works but not `get`

There are a few other methods which I tried from the documentation but either `get` works but it'll be open to public that anyone knows the `url` will be able to see the data for `get`, but I want to set restriction that only `example.this-one.com` can get `example.that-two.com`

Can someone give me some advice on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly setting `methods`

Comment: @thomann061 where can I find sample for the `explicitly setting methods`?

Comment: `app.use(cors())` enables cors to all requests, even `get`s

Comment: Yes - I suspect the options get overwritten.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @thomann061 pretty much just `'Not allowed by CORS' at origin (where file is :33:78)`

Comment: @Dora try using `app.use(cors())` then create a simple endpoint like `app.get('/', (req, res) => { res.status(200).send('Hello World!'); });` and see if it's woking

Comment: @guijob that works but that's opening up all the cors, I am trying to restrict instead of enable all

Comment: @Dora, that's ok. at least it's not an issue with your browser. now try using your cors options into this same simple endpoint like: `app.get('/', cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => { res.status(200).send('Hello World!'); });` and see if it's woking

Answer (score -1):

Since the server is `http://example.that-two.com`, put the client (`http://example.this-one.com`) on the whitelist

```
var whitelist = ['http://example.this-one.com']
var corsOptions = {
    origin: function (origin, callback) {
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
            callback(null, true)
        } else {
            callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'))
        }
    },
    methods: ['GET']
}
```

This will allow all `GET` requests from `http://example.this-one.com`

Then call the middleware:

```
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

Answer (score -1):

The following code is working for me:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

Comment: actually I added that too :|